# To print or not to print in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

When talking about pytest we know two things:

1. When a test pass, no output is given in principle
2. Sometimes the assertion failures can have very cryptic messages.

I took a course that solved this by using `print` to clarify desired outputs and calling the pytest as `pytest -v -s`. I think it is a great solution

Another developer in my company thinks that test code should be as free of "side effects" as possible (and considers prints as side effect). He suggests outputting to a file which I think it is not a good practice. (I think *that* is an undesirable side effect)

So I would like to hear about this from other developers.
How do you solve the two points given in the beginning and do you use prints in your tests?

Comment: _Sometimes the assertion failures can have very cryptic messages_ Then provide your own message.  `assert some_condition, "custom message here for assertion failure"`

Comment: I do but a team manager thinks that is not enough clarity

Answer (score 1):

As someone already pointed out you can provide your own assert message:

```py
def test_something():
    i = 2
    assert i == 1, "i should be equal to one"
```

There should be really no difference between using assert messages and prints, but in case of an assert message only it would be visible in pytest report, and not all the stdout calls:
In this case 0-9 would be printed in pytest report

```py
def test_something():
    i = 2
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
    assert i == 1
```

Logging everything to a file would definitely make working with pytest harder, and would be a pain to debug if your tests fail in CI.
If you need descriptive messages I would prefer using assert messages and, maybe, prints for debug information.

Answer (score 1):

using print() in your test is not a good solution, you need to see data in cli or on a pipeline.
so for assertion you can share custom messages for assertion in pass or fail case or even in raise an exception
here is a basic tutorial for this
https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/assert.html

for general test steps the best way to get the info is logging
logging on different levels

```
import logging as logger
logger.info('what info you want to share')
logger.error('what info you want to share')
logger.debug('what info you want to share')
```

for more info you can check this
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html